# SQL How to Join and Summarize

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Edited to provide code and progress towards solution]

I have a couple of tables built by an SSIS job that copies invoices from an accounting system and time entries from a billing system.  As we are a services company, we bill according to four simple rates.  The task at hand is to build a query that matches the hours invoiced by rate to the hour accumulated from the billing system by time period.

I've derived a column thru the SSIS job that identifies the next Monday relative to the time entry record.  As we invoice on Mondays, I now have a way to tie activity in a given week to the invoice being created in the following week.  The curve ball I've just encountered is accounting wants to invoice on different, non-weekly, periods.  Work still happens each week, but I can't just do a simple join between my invoice date and the derived Monday.

Historically, I would pivot the invoice rows and time entries to summarize by rate.  I'm avoiding that because it may represent presuppositions that distract from an answer.  Here's a simplified view of the two tables

Invoice Rows

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
|Inv. Date | Inv. Num | Qty Hours | Rate  | Job ID|
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| 5-7-18   | 12345    |  10       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-7-18   | 12345    |  5        | Eng   |  1    |
| 5-7-18   | 12345    |  20       | Design|  1    |
| 5-7-18   | 12345    |  2        | Staff |  1    |
| 5-14-18  | 12370    |  90       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-14-18  | 12370    |  10       | Eng   |  1    |
| 5-14-18  | 12370    |  8        | Design|  1    |
| 5-14-18  | 12370    |  1        | Staff |  1    |
| 5-28-18  | 12390    |  20       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-28-18  | 12390    |  10       | Eng   |  1    |
| 5-28-18  | 12390    |  80       | Design|  1    |
| 5-28-18  | 12390    |  1        | Staff |  1    |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

Time Entries

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
|Date Enter| Next Mon | Qty Hours | Rate  | Job ID|
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| 5-1-18   | 5-7-18   |  10       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-3-18   | 5-7-18   |  5        | Eng   |  1    |
| 5-3-18   | 5-7-18   |  10       | Design|  1    |
| 5-4-18   | 5-7-18   |  10       | Design|  1    |
| 5-4-18   | 5-7-18   |  2        | Staff |  1    |
| 5-7-18   | 5-14-18  |  20       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-8-18   | 5-14-18  |  20       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-9-18   | 5-14-18  |  20       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-11-18  | 5-14-18  |  30       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-10-18  | 5-14-18  |  10       | Eng   |  1    |
| 5-11-18  | 5-14-18  |  8        | Design|  1    |
| 5-12-18  | 5-14-18  |  1        | Staff |  1    |
| 5-15-18  | 5-21-18  |  10       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-16-18  | 5-21-18  |  5        | Eng   |  1    |
| 5-17-18  | 5-21-18  |  40       | Design|  1    |
| 5-18-18  | 5-21-18  |  .5       | Staff |  1    |
| 5-21-18  | 5-28-18  |  10       | Draft |  1    |
| 5-22-18  | 5-28-18  |  5        | Eng   |  1    |
| 5-23-18  | 5-28-18  |  40       | Design|  1    |
| 5-25-18  | 5-28-18  |  .5       | Staff |  1    |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

The output I'm looking for follows:

```
+-------+------+--------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
|InvDate|InvNum|InvDraft|InvEng|InvDes|InvStaff|TeDraft|TeEng|TeDes|TeStaff|
+-------+------+--------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
|5-7-18 |12345 | 10     | 5    |  20  | 2      | 10    | 5   |  20 |   2   |
|5-14-18|12370 | 90     | 10   |  8   | 1      | 90    | 10  |  8  |   1   |
|5-28-18|12390 | 20     | 10   |  80  | 1      | 20    | 10  |  80 |   1   |
+-------+------+--------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+-------+
```

The trick for me is figuring out how  to aggregate two-weeks worth of billing from the Time Entry side.  I never know how many weeks will fall between invoices, so I need to let the dates of the invoices that exist drive it.

Here's the SQL so far:

```
USE FiniteAccounting
GO

WITH
Invoices AS
    (SELECT JrnlHdrs.TransactionDate
            , JrnlRows.InvNumForThisTrx
            , JrnlHdrs.ShipToName
            , JrnlHdrs.CustVendId
            , JrnlRows.JobID
            , EPProjects.Name AS ProjectName
            , EPProjects.EstimatedHours
            , EPProjects.QtHours
            , EPProjects.PONumber AS PurchOrder
            , EPProjects.QTPrice
            , JrnlHdrs.AmountPaid
            , Customer.CustomerRecordNumber
            , JrnlRows.Quantity
            , JrnlRows.Rate
            , InvSum.InvHours
      FROM  JrnlHdrs JrnlHdrs INNER JOIN
            JrnlRows JrnlRows ON JrnlRows.PostOrder = JrnlHdrs.PostOrder INNER JOIN
            EPProjects EPProjects ON EPProjects.ProjNumber = JrnlRows.JobID INNER JOIN
            Customer Customer ON Customer.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdrs.CustVendId INNER JOIN
            (SELECT JrnlRows.InvNumForThisTrx, sum(jrnlRows.Quantity) AS InvHours 
                FROM JrnlRows
                Group By JrnlRows.InvNumForThisTrx) As InvSum on InvSum.InvNumForThisTrx = JrnlRows.InvNumForThisTrx
      Where JrnlRows.Quantity > 0 AND EPProjects.ProjectStatusID = 3),

InvoicePVT AS
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(PARTITION BY JobId ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC) AS RowID
            , TransactionDate
            , InvNumForThisTrx
            , ShipToName
            , CustVendId
            , JobID
            , ProjectName
            , IsNull([StaffEng], 0) AS StaffEng
            , IsNull(Engineer, 0) AS Engineer
            , IsNull(Designer, 0) AS Designer
            , IsNull(Draftsman, 0) AS Draftsman
            , InvHours
            , EstimatedHours
            , QtHours
            , PurchOrder AS PONumber
            , IsNull(QTPrice, 0) AS QTPrice
            , AmountPaid
            , CustomerRecordNumber
    FROM    Invoices PIVOT (SUM(Quantity) FOR Rate IN ([Draftsman], [Designer], [Engineer], [StaffEng])) AS RatesPerRow)

Select      i1.TransactionDate as LastInvDate 
            , i2.TransactionDate
            , i2.InvNumForThisTrx
            --, i2.ShipToName
            --, i2.CustVendId
            , i2.JobID
            --, i2.ProjectName
            , IsNull(i2.StaffEng, 0) AS StaffEng
            , IsNull(i2.Engineer, 0) AS Engineer
            , IsNull(i2.Designer, 0) AS Designer
            , IsNull(i2.Draftsman, 0) AS Draftsman
            , i2.InvHours

From InvoicePVT i1 INNER JOIN InvoicePVT i2 ON i1.RowID = i2.rowid -1
WHERE i1.JobID = i2.JobID;
```

The Results are:

```
LastInvDate TransactionDate InvNumForThisTrx    JobID   StaffEng    Engineer    Designer    Draftsman   InvHours
2017-05-22  2017-05-29  11216   16-2256 0   0   29.75   0   30.25
2017-05-29  2017-06-05  11232   16-2256 0   0.25    34  0   34.25
2017-06-05  2017-06-12  11250   16-2256 0   0   41.75   0   41.75
2017-06-12  2017-06-19  11267   16-2256 0   0   17.5    0   17.5
2017-06-19  2017-06-26  11283   16-2256 0   1   9   0   10
2017-06-26  2017-07-10  11304   16-2256 0   0   1.25    0   1.25
2017-07-10  2017-11-06  11698   16-2256 0   1.25    1.25    0   2.5
2017-11-06  2018-04-09  12184   16-2256 0   0.75    33  0   33.75
2018-04-09  2018-04-23  12212   16-2256 0   0   12.25   0   12.25
2018-04-23  2018-05-14  12263   16-2256 0   0.5 5   0   5.5
2018-04-09  2018-04-23  12186   18-4080 0   1.25    1   8.5 10.75
2018-04-23  2018-04-30  12214   18-4080 0   0.5 0   7.5 8
2018-04-30  2018-05-14  12234   18-4080 0   1.75    1.25    56.5    59.5
2018-05-14  2018-05-28  12266   18-4080 0   0.5 1.25    34  35.75
2018-05-28  2018-05-28  12293   18-4080 0   1   0   44.75   45.75
2018-05-28  2018-05-28  12294   18-4080 0   0   0   17.25   17.25
2018-05-28  2018-05-28  12295   18-4080 0   0   0   9.75    9.75
2018-05-28  2018-05-28  12296   18-4080 0   0   0   5.75    5.75
2018-05-14  2018-05-28  12265   18-4088 0   0   0   0   10
2018-05-14  2018-05-28  12281   18-4089 0   0.75    18.5    0   19.25
2018-05-14  2018-05-28  12278   18-4102 0   0.75    15  0   15.75
```

Thanks in advance!
Perry

Answer (score 0):

First create a table from  distinct "Next Mon" column. lets name it "BillingMondays".
Then Create an additional column which stores row number for  "BillingMondays". Lets Call it "BillingMondayNo".
Now join "BillingMondays" with itself on BillingMondayNo = BillingMondayNo - 1. This connect a record of BillingMondays to its previous record and from it you  can calculate the weekly-distance of the bills.
I think this would solve your problem

Comment: this seems to have me on the right path.  I'm updating the post with the code and results I have so far, hoping for an additional boost.  The major issue lies in the first invoice essentially being dropped - Row 1 doesn't appear as it doesn't have a preceding invoice.  I still need it.  Comments appreciated!